# How to run code exactly once in LD_PRELOADed shared library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, posix, ld-preload

The following code demonstrates that when using `LD_PRELOAD`, the library can be loaded multiple times in the *same* process (constructors called multiple times and static data initialized multiple times).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern bool initialized = false;

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) setup() {
    printf("constructor %d %d %d\n", getpid(), gettid(), initialized);
    initialized = true;
}
```

The experiment can be run with the following commands:

```
$ gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so lib.c

$ env LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libtest.so sh -c ls
constructor 98928 98928 0
constructor 98928 98928 0
... rest of output of ls
```

Note that the PID is the same; this is not a problem due to forking. Note that the `initialized` variable is 0, presumably because each time the library gets loaded, the loader puts the static section in to a new place memory. I know that replacing `sh -c ls` with just `ls` *would* cause the library to be loaded only once in this particular case, but not generally.

How does one run code exactly once in an `LD_PRELOAD`ed library for arbitrary command?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `sh`, the library is loaded, and the constructor runs. Then, because of the `-c "$cmd"`, the shell calls an `exec` routine to completely replace the process with a new program. Nearly everything about the previous program is wiped away, including the loaded libraries. Then the new program starts, so the library is loaded again, and the constructor runs again. The system is not running the constructor twice in the same program; it is two separate programs, one after the other in the same process.

> I know that replacing `sh -c "$cmd"` with just `$cmd` *would* cause the library to be loaded only once in this particular case,…
>
> How does one run code exactly once in an `LD_PRELOAD`ed library?

As you write, replace `sh -c "$cmd"` with `$cmd`.

Comment: Why do you say `$cmd` could not expand to `sh -c something`?

Comment: @charmoniumQ: As you wrote it, without `something` I thought you were saying `$cmd` was equivalent to `sh -c "$cmd"`. Since that is not what you meant, I deleted that part.

Comment: then this does not answer the question "how to ensure code is run only once per process", if it will only work for certain values of `$cmd`.

Comment: @charmoniumQ: (a) It is impossible as long as `LD_PRELOAD` is set, because, as explained, `sh -c command` uses `exec` to completely restart the process as a new program. (b) This does not result in any duplication of global data, because the two programs are entirely separate. (c) If, for some reason, you need it not to happen, then sanitize `cmd` in the shell script before executing it as a command.

Comment: (b) duplicated code could matter if it has side effects outside the program, e.g., printing something to stdout, writing to the file system.

How would (c) work? Presumably there are commands other than `sh -c` which would also cause the problem?

Comment: @charmoniumQ: If you do not have control of what is in `cmd`, you have a much bigger problem than whether a library will be initialized twice. `cmd` could fork multiple processes, delete files, introduce malicious software, and more.

Comment: I am trying to create a tool like `strace`, so we can assume the user already trusts and wants to run `$cmd`. I don't see that as a problem for this application.